# How to switch workspaces in jackrabbit based on user login?

Tags: java, jackrabbit

If I have 2 workspaces configured (e.g. default and temp), how to choose which Jackrabbit workspace to use? In other words: How can I switch workspaces via Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repository.login() takes an optional String argument that identifies the workspace.

```
public Session login(Credentials credentials, java.lang.String workspaceName)
```

[Docs for Repository.login()](http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-1.0/javax/jcr/Repository.html#login(javax.jcr.Credentials,%20java.lang.String))